# FilledInput label outside of text field

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using `<FilledInput/>` from Material UI along with `<InputLabel/>` but for some reason the label is not vertically centered and goes "out of bounds" when focused (as if it's the outlined version). I could use "filled" variant of the normal `<TextField/>` but `<FilledInput/>` is cleaner to style to my liking. Does anyone perhaps know why the label alignment is so wrong though?

Codesandbox here demonstrates how differently it behaves from the usual "filled" variant TextField:
https://codesandbox.io/s/filled-field-example-4hqqkw?file=/demo.tsx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible reason why the label alignment is wrong is that you are using the FilledInput component without wrapping it inside a FormControl component. According to the Material UI documentation, the FilledInput component should be used as a child of FormControl, which provides context such as filled/focused/error/required for form inputs.

For example:

```
<FormControl size="small" fullWidth variant="filled">
...
</FormControl>
```

This is a result.

[image: This works fine]

Comment: It is wrapped with FormControl in the code sandbox so unfortunately not that. But thanks for thinking along!

Comment: Have you added `variant="filled"` to your form control?

Comment: Oh my gosh! That totally was the missing piece! I didn't realise I had to specify the variant in the Form Control as well even if already explicitly imported the FilledInput. Thank you so much Victor! I was very close to throwing in the towel in my project and you saved me!

Comment: You're welcome. If you have any questions, please let me know.